# Unable to concatenate string from line-by-line text file

Tags: shell, unix, trim

I have a shell script which is supposed to build and run an SQL request.
The SQL request looks like this:

```
select distinct USER from USER_CONNECTIONS where USER is not in ('user1','user2','user3')
```

This part of the SQL request:

```
('user1','user2','user3')
```

is built by a shell function that reads a text file containing the data as following:

```
>> userList.txt
user1
user2
user3
```

The function is the following:

```
get_where_authorized()
{
    WHERE_NOT_IN="("
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        WHERE_NOT_IN+="'$line', "
    done < "DB_authorizations.txt"
    WHERE_NOT_IN+="'')"
    echo $WHERE_NOT_IN
}
```

So, I store this string into a variable:

```
AUTHORIZED_USERS="$(get_where_authorized)"
```

... and when I echo this variable, the result looks good:

```
bash$ echo $AUTHORIZED_USERS
('user1', 'user2', 'user3', '')
```

However, when I try to use this string into my SQL request, it seems there's a carriage return (`\n`) right after the first user:

```
bash$ MY_SQL="select distinct USER from USER_CONNECTIONS where USER is not in $AUTHORIZED_USERS"
bash$ echo $MY_SQL
select distinct USER from USER_CONNECTIONS where USER is not in ('user1',
```

The above SQL request, clearly, generates an error when executed. 
I'm trying to understand why this happens: it seems that the carriage returns are hidden when I echo the variable `AUTHORIZED_USERS`, but that they are taken when used in the SQL string.

I've tried to trim them out:

```
AUTHORIZED_USERS="$(get_where_authorized)" | tr -d '\n'
```

but still no chance. 
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What error msg your are getting?

Comment: @Abhijit it's not an error message per-se, it's just the string "MY_SQL" echoed shows that it's cut after the first line read by the file. On one hand, this lets me understand that a carriage return is put right after the line parsing. On the other hand, the error message comes from the sqlplus when I try to execute the query (saying just "invalid SQL").

Comment: You can take the help of `awk` command.

Answer (score 0):

Trim the '\r' character as well. 
Also, the syntax you've used while trimming is incorrect. '$(variable)' behaves like backticks and tries to execute the value of the variable.

The correct code should be:

```
AUTHORIZED_USERS=$(echo "$get_where_authorized" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\r')
```